# Selenium click in headless mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to wrap my brain around this problem. I have a webscraping project with Selenium and my script works when headless mode is disabled. Once I add the argument ("--headless") to my chrome driver options (chrome driver version 88.0.4324) it isn't able to click the element. I have seen other people mentioning that maximizing the window or setting the window size of the headless driver will solve this, I have had no luck with such solutions.

This is the line that clicks the element:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a [@href][@class="button icon arrowdown"]').click()
```

This is what I was using before the above xpath:

```
browser.find_element_by_class('button icon arrowdown').click()
```

Thanks for Everyones Help!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue tried using javascript click

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('button icon arrowdown')[0].click()")
```

Comment: And what happened? Has it fixed it for you?

Comment: So I excuted the script gave above, I didn't get any errors so I can assume the chrome driver recieved the javascript just fine, but the button wasn't interacted with unfortuantly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot and snapshot of the headless window when exception occurs. That will help you to find out why this happens. You can try to use selene library https://github.com/yashaka/selene which already have these features, or write your own snap-shooter.

Depending on this quote

> I have seen other people mentioning that maximizing the window or
> setting the window size of the headless driver will solve this, I have
> had no luck with such solutions.

you need to know, that maximizing in headless - doesn't work because it headless and doesn't know which screen size is to maximize.
You should take the dimensions of the browser in non-headless mode and set it up directly in selenium both for head and headless mode. This can solve your issue. And even if not - try to take screenshot or make a video to figure out what's going on in headless mode.

Comment: Everything apears to be present that is needed! I tried assigning the window demensions instead of maximizing the window, and still no luck.